# Use standard pop-up items on BlackBerry

Tags: menu, popup, blackberry, contextmenu

I'd like to use a standard "delete" operation on a component I implemented, instead of defining a custom icon and text (with all possible translation) for a "standard" operation.

That is: if I keep my finger on the icon, I expect a pop-up menu to appear, with the standard "delete" icon and text.

Is it possible, without reimplementing it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't possible, I copied the standard icon from a simulator screenshot, and used it for the pop-up menu.